# Django extend custom manager at runtime. Mixin style?

Tags: python, django

The following code is part of a TranslatedContent class which adds a custom manager to the model.

```
if hasattr(cls, 'objects'):
    if cls.objects.__class__ == models.Manager:
        # default manager, override
        cls.add_to_class('objects', TranslationManager()
    else:
        # there is a custom manager, don't override
        cls.add_to_class('translated', TranslationManager())
```

When a custom manager is already present it uses a different name for the manager. ('translated' in this case) That's not what I want.

How can I use the same name ('objects') and still overwrite it with TranslationManager()?
In stead of overwrite that would be an override/extend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *could* do something like:

```
if hasattr(cls, 'objects'):
    if cls.objects.__class__ == models.Manager:
        # default manager, override
        cls.add_to_class('objects', TranslationManager()
    else:
        # there is a custom manager, don't override
        class CombinedManager(cls.objects.__class__, TranslationManager):
            pass
        cls.add_to_class('objects', CombinedManager())
```

But, you need to be extremely cautious about the namespace, in particular conflicts that might occur between the original manager and your `TranslationManager`. In general, it's best to leave it to the end-user to determine whether or not they want their custom manager to include the `TranslationManager` as well.

I'd recommend simply putting it in the documentation that `TranslationManager` will only be added as the default manager if a custom manager isn't present. Otherwise, the user should have their custom manager inherit from `TranslationManager` to gain that functionality.

Comment: thanks, you're right, i'll go with the documentation option. Is it 'not-done' to throw a warning if a custom manager is present?

Comment: It's debatable. If it's important enough, as in they really need to use your `TranslationManager`, and you're basically just using the warning as a reminder (i.e. if they neglected to do it, it was only because they forgot, not because they chose not to), then a warning is perhaps appropriate. Otherwise, it's best to leave it alone.